# Which scripture contains the details about the aniconic idols of the three pañcāyatana deities - Sūrya, Gaṇeśa, and Devī?

Tags: puja, idols, smarta, pancayatana

It is well known that besides being worshipped in their 'saguṇa' mūrti forms, both Śiva and Viṣṇu are also worshipped by their 'self-manifested' aniconic idols viz - the Śivaliṅga [Bāṇaliṅga ( बाणलिङ्ग )], and the Śāligrāma (शालिग्राम).

These two aniconic idols of Śiva and Viṣṇu are also used as such in the Smārta-sect's pañcāyatana form of worship, which involve five deities, viz. Sūrya, Gaṇeśa, Devī, Śiva and Viṣṇu, and it is referred to as Pañcāyatanapūjā or 'the worship of five deities. The five 'self-manifested' idols are said to be found at and procured from a specific river-geographical location only.

All the pañcāyatana deities in the Smārta-sect are depicted by their an anionic idol which may be tabulated as follows:

#### The  Pañcāyatanapūjā deities & their 'representational stones'.

| Sr. No. | Deity | Anionic Idol | Geographic location of the Idol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Sūrya | Vallam Crystal stone | Vallam river in Tanjavur district, Tamil Nadu |
| 2. | Gaṇeśa | Red Sonabhadra Shila | Sone Rive in Mirzapur, Uttar Pradesh |
| 3. | Devī | Swarna Mukhi (Rekha Shila) | Swarnamukhi river (Srikalahasti) in Andhra Pradesh |
| 4. | Śiva | Bāṇaliṅga | Narmada river (Omkara-kunda) in Madhya Pradesh |
| 5. | Viṣṇu | Śāligrāma-śilā | Kali Gandaki River, a tributary of the Gandaki River in Nepal |

Now, references for worshipping the Śivaliṅga and the Śāligrāma can be found in several scriptures like Skanda Purana: [here (Śāligrāma)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc502222.html), and [here (Bāṇaliṅga)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc365980.html), or Padma Purana: [here ( Śāligrāma)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365710.html) and [here (Bāṇaliṅga)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365426.html), etc.

But, I don't know of any such references in regards to the other three deities viz. Sūrya, Gaṇeśa and Devī.

---

### Question:

Which canonical scripture contain references about using and worshipping, the aniconic idols (mūrtis/vigraha) of Sūrya, Gaṇeśa, and the Devī as mentioned above?